# ActionBar tab background with xml

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, nine-patch

Is it possibile to create a Holo-like ActionBar tab background **only** with xml drawables? If yes, how? If no, what's the limitation?

[image]

Browsing the Android source code I found that the tab background is defined with a selector drawable in [tab_indicator_holo.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/tab_indicator_holo.xml):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
</selector>
```

And then using 9 patch drawables for each state, such as [tab_selected_holo.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/tab_selected_holo.9.png).

I was wondering if those 9 patch drawables could be replaced with layer list drawables, shape drawables or a combination, thus saving the need to create various PNG files (6 per density by my count).

I noticed that [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) also uses 9 patch drawables, so it's highly likely this is the only way to do it.

Comment: What I do is copy them from the android platform resources folder and tweak them a little bit

Comment: @ferdy182 That's what I do too, and I would prefer to avoid it. I don't like hardcoding the appearance and color of a tab in 18 files.

Comment: maybe this helps a little although it doesn't answer your question http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use shapes or other drawables in place of 9-patch

Comment: @CSmith Can you provide an example? Say, make tab_selected_holo as a 9-patch?

Answer (score 2):

To completely customize your ActionBar tabs, try something like the following, for a fictional tab called "Home".  This layout contains an image and label.

(1) create the tab as normal, but specify a custom layout via ActionBar.Tab.setCustomView()

```
// Home tab
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
RelativeLayout layoutView = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tab_home, null);
TextView title = (TextView)layoutView.findViewById(R.id.title);
ImageView img = (ImageView)layoutView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
ActionBar.Tab tabHome = mActionBar.newTab();
tabHome.setTabListener(homeFragment);
title.setText(this.getString(R.string.tabTitleHome));
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab_home);
tabHome.setCustomView(layoutView);
mActionBar.addTab(tabHome);
```

(2) create a layout for your tab (layout_tab_home.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="56dip" android:layout_weight="0" android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/icon" android:paddingLeft="0dip" android:paddingRight="0dip" style="@style/tabText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(3) set a drawable for your image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home_sel" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/home_unsel" />
</selector>
```

in this example, I just have a PNG graphic with diff't colors for selected vs. unselected states

You seem to be most interested in the BACKGROUND drawable, so the same thing would apply, but set a background drawable on your RelativeLayout, and use a selector similar to the above.

Comment: I think that the question is about not using PNGs at all but using only composed drawables instead

Comment: Yes. Not what I was asking, but thans for trying anyway CSmith.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inset drawables to create the line strip at the bottom. This xml will create a white rectangle with a blue line at the bottom like the one you posted. Then you can use state list drawables for its state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:insetBottom="0dp"
android:insetLeft="-5dp"
android:insetRight="-5dp"
android:insetTop="-5dp" >

<shape>
    <solid android:color="#FFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#00F" />
</shape>
</inset>
```

For more info you can have a look at this post: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1329